# Web Design - Include font on server or similar?

Tags: fonts

An issue I'm having is using CSS's font-family code to change the font of my website's text. However, the issue is that the font I need is not native to Windows. I know I could download the font and view it like that. But this is of course not a valid solution for my viewers. Is there any way I can include a font package on my server so that all viewers regardless of OS or having the font can view the font I choose? Any help would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google fonts is the best way to do this! Using @import in a stylesheet is how I got it!